# Testing if the terminal supports pseudographics

Tags: python, linux, unicode

I'm writing a Python program which tabulates some data to stdout, and I'd like to use fancy [Unicode box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) if the terminal supports it.

Now there are three ways I can do it:

- Blindly output Unicode and hope the user doesn't get a screenful of garbage, or
- Always use ASCII, or
- Do some checks, and fallback to ASCII if necessary.

What checks can I do? The best I can think of is checking whether the terminal has a UTF-8 locale. However, this is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition, because the user might not have any fonts that support box-drawing characters; or else he might use a different locale which *does* support line-drawing characters.

Comment: Is [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) a possibility? It should know the terminal's capabilities, and the best way to leverage them.

Comment: Hmm. Can curses output a character to stdout, without any positioning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could test-encode your characters with `sys.stdout.encoding` in a `try/except` block to see if the output encoding will support the characters:

```
#!python3
#coding:utf8

import sys

try:
    '┌┬┐╔╦╗╒╤╕╓╥╖│║─═├┼┤╠╬╣╞╪╡╟╫╢└┴┘╚╩╝╘╧╛╙╨╜'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    test = True
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    test = False

if not test:
    print('Unsupported characters in',sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Output:

```
C:\>chcp 437
C:\>test
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252
C:\>test
Unsupported characters in cp1252
```

Comment: This is the "checking whether the terminal has a UTF-8 locale" approach OP finds "neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition"

Comment: @thatotherguy, no, this doesn't check that it has a *UTF-8* locale...it checks  that it has a locale that supports the characters.  It satisfies the "he might use a different locale which *does* support line-drawing characters."

Comment: Fair enough, it supports a variety of legacy DOS and IBM codepages. It does not support the much more common case of Linux/Unix terminals that do box drawing through alternate sets though.

Comment: @thatotherguy Why shouldn't it? It just tests if the terminal supports the tested characters. So if the terminal can display them, why should a program be unable to draw its own boxes using those characters?

Comment: @Lampe2020 "Alternate set" is a terminal mode that changes how the terminal draws characters. When enabled, `r` becomes `⎼`, so `printf '\e(0rrrrrrrrrrr\e(B\n'` draws a horizontal line. Verifying that you can encode `r` by itself is obviously not useful. This may have been worth exploring in 2015, but in 2023 anyone without a UTF-8 terminal can eat ASCII art.

Comment: @thatotherguy Wow, I wouldn't want my programs to return a random collection of characters when they try to say something in simple text! But thanks for the explanation!